# How can Kundala of Karna protect him in battle?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, history, karna

In mahabharatha Karna's *Kavacha* and *Kundalas* made him invincible in   battle.

- Kavacha *armour* protecting his chest.
- In which way *kundalas* protect him which are in his **ears** ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because Kavacha and Kundala of Karna contained Amrita in them as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03305.htm) of Vana Parva of Mahabharata:

> Thereupon Kunti said, 'If, O dispeller of darkness, I obtain a son from thee, may he be furnished with a coat of mail and ear-rings, and may he be mighty-armed and endued with great strength!' Hearing these words of hers, Surya answered, 'O gentle maiden, thy son shall be mighty-armed and decked with ear-rings and a celestial coat of mail. **And both his ear-rings and coat of mail will be made of Amrita,** and his coat will also be invulnerable.' Kunti then said, 'If the excellent mail and ear-rings of the son thou wilt beget on me, be, indeed, made of Amrita, then, O god, O worshipful deity, let thy purpose be fulfilled! May he be powerful, strong, energetic, and handsome, even like thee, and may he also be endued with virtue!' Surya then said, 'O princess, O excellent damsel, these ear-rings had been given to me by Aditi. O timid lady, I will bestow them, as also this excellent mail, on thy son!' Kunti then said, 'Very well, O worshipful one! If my son, O lord of light, become so, I will, as thou sayest, gratify thee!'

As it was made up of Amrita, it would make Karnas body immortal until Kavacha/Kundala were attached to his body due to effect of Amrita. In this way Kundala also protected him.

Comment: I agree with your answer for kavasha and kundalas made of amirta but as you know some of battles of karna many astras striked his coat and stopped by it likewise is there any battles in which kundalas stopped any attack or kundalas power told

Comment: @sakthi Kundalas are very small.. it's highly unlikely that they will protect from any astra as Kavach does.. and further people wear Kavach for their protection from Astra.. Nobody wears Kundala thinking that it can protect as Kavach does..

Comment: if kundalas cannot protect him then what is the need for it to be made of amirta and give it to karna and lord indra would have asked only the KAVASHA and not kundalas

Comment: @sakthi Indra asked Kundalas also because it contained Amrita.. ie. If someone cut Karnas whole body into pieces then it will again be fit due to effect of Amrita of Kundals.. in this way he would be immortal.. I'm just saying Kundala doesn't protect anyone **physically** as Kavacha does..

Comment: so kundalas can again fit him into one body is there scriptures for this friend

Comment: @sakthi I don't understand what you are asking..? For how Amrita works you can see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/how-does-the-soul-returns-in-the-dead-body-when-a-dead-person-is-revived-using-a

Comment: i have another question if both kundalas and kavasha are made of amirta then kavasha can also make his legs or hands to be free from any disease or injuries correct friend

Answer (score 1):

Kundalas (ear rings) are reflected the sun light or moon light to his enemy's eyes just like seeing sun  .. so karnas enemy could not hit karna with there arrows... So this tiny help from kundalas karna is impossible to win from his enemy's

Comment: You should cite some sources.