# Is Karna described as a weak warrior in Hindu scripture?

Tags: karna

In popular belief, Karna is usually viewed as a strong warrior, perhaps even stronger than Arjuna.  But my question is, does Hindu scripture ever describe Karna as a weak warrior?  (I'm not asking about events that answerers may subjectively characterize as weak or strong, I'm just asking about scriptural statements that explicitly say he's weak.)

And if Hindu scripture does explicitly say that he's weak, does it give a reason for his weakness?

Comment: Although Karna was defeated many times but he was immortal due to presence of Amrita in his Kavacha and Kundala.. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16351/how-can-kundala-of-karna-protect-him-in-battle/16352#16352

Comment: He wasn't. Read this- http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07177.htm

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based. One can give examples to support or refute this premise.

Comment: I edited your question to make it a purely factual question and then reopened it.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>I felt obliged to answer this Question, as many people misunderstood my [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10767/1049). I no way projected Karna as a weak warrior. But there was never an opportunity to express that. Thanks for reopening this thread.</sub>

The answer is **NO**.
In fact Karna was considered one of the strongest.
On the backdrop of Ghatotkacha's death, Krishna describes Karna's warring greatness in following ways:

1. With *Kavacha-Kundala*, he was **invincible**; *Sudarshana chakra* even cannot kill him
2. Without *Kavacha-Kundala*, but with Indra's dart (divine weapon), he was **indefeasible**
3. Without any of above, he was still **indefeasible by anyone except Arjuna**; Even Arjuna also might have to adopt some deceit to vanquish Karna

[Drona Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07177.htm):

> Vasudeva said, ..., O Dhananjaya, that Karna, his dart being baffled through Ghatotkacha, is already slain in battle. **The man does not exist in this world that could stay before Karna armed with that dart** and looking like Kartikeya in battle. By good luck, his (natural) armour had been taken away. By good luck, his earrings also had been taken away. By good luck, his infallible dart also is now baffled, through Ghatotkacha. Clad in (natural) coat of mail and decked with his (natural) ear-rings, Karna, who had his senses under control, could singly vanquish the three worlds with the very gods. Neither Vasava, nor Varuna the lord of the waters, nor Yama, could venture to approach him. Indeed, **if that bull among men had his armour and ear-rings, neither thyself, bending the Gandiva, nor myself, uplifting my discus, called Sudarsana, could vanquish him in battle.** For thy good, Karna was divested of his ear-rings by Sakra with the help of an illusion. Similarly was that subjugator of hostile towns deprived of his (natural) armour. ... But **though deprived of that dart, O sinless one, I swear to thee that hero is still incapable of being slain by anybody else save thee**. He is incapable of being vanquished in battle by the gods ... When his car-wheels will sink in the earth, availing thyself of that opportunity, **thou shouldst slay him in that distressful situation** ...

Comment: Welcome back on main site. It is not about your previous answer on  karna. Your previous was comparing with arjuna. So, when compared, he is. The OP already has  a prejudice on Karna. Intact he has a blog which has an article about the defeats of Karna. He posted all that content directly as a question here. So your previous answer will/should not be blamed for this question.

Comment: @SreeCharan, thanks, though it's intended only for this answer as of now :-). Actually in my previous answer there were few people who felt that my answer was disgracing Karna. To refute my answer, some users even posted answers, which were later converted comments. If we see Quora, or other media, there are many "Karna fan clubs". Similarly there are "Arjuna fan clubs" too. "Arjuna" supporters usually bring down Karna based on his stand on Dharma. Similarly "Karna" followers bring down Arjuna on warring abilities. Though we may find it funny, those people are quite serious about it.

Answer (score 3):

**Is Karna described as a weak warrior in Hindu scripture?**

NO, contrary to that this is what Indra said about Karna in [Mahabharata:Svargarohanika Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m18/m18003.htm):

> 17 कर्णश चैव महेष्वासः **सर्वशस्त्रभृतां वरः**
>        स गतः परमां सिद्धिं यदर्थं परितप्यसे
>
> 18 तं पश्य पुरुषव्याघ्रम आदित्यतनयं विभॊ
>        सवस्थानस्थं महाबाहॊ जहि शॊकं नरर्षभ

वरः (varaH) = excellent

सर्वशस्त्रभृतां (sarvashastrabhRitaam) = among all the wielders of weapon

> Karna, the mighty bowman, that **foremost of all wielders of weapons** for whom thou art grieving, has also attained to high success. Behold, O puissant one, that foremost of men, viz., the son of Surya. He is in that place which is his own, O mighty-armed one. Kill this grief of thine, O chief of men.

Answer (score 2):

Karna lied to Parashurama that he was a brahmana in order to study under him, since Parashurama had taken vow to teach only  brahmanas and not kshatriyas.

> One day Rama of great intelligence, while roving with Karna in the vicinity or his retreat, felt very weak in consequence of the fasts he had undergone. From affection begotten by confidence, the tired son of Jamadagni placing his head on Karna's lap, slept soundly, White his preceptor was thus sleeping (with head) on his lap, a frightful worm, whose bite was very painful and which subsisted on phlegm and fat and flesh and blood, approached the presence of Karna. That blood-sucking worm, approaching Karna's thigh, began to pierce it. Through fear of (awaking) his preceptor, Karna became unable to either throw away or kill that worm. Though his limb was bored through by that worm, O Bharata, the son of Surya, lest his preceptor should awake, suffered it to do its pleasure. Though the pain was intolerable, Karna bore it with heroic patience, and continued to hold Bhrigu's son on his lap, without quivering in the least and without manifesting any sign of pain. When at last Karna's blood touched the body of Rama of great energy, the latter awoke and said these words in fear, 'Alas, I have been made impure! What is this that thou art doing, Tell me, casting off all fear, what is the truth of this matter!' Then Karna informed him of that worm's bite. Rama saw that worm which resembled a hog in shape. It had eight feet and very keen teeth, and it was covered with bristles that were all pointed like needles. Called by the name of Alarka, its limbs were then shrunk (with fear). As soon as Rama cast his, eyes on it, the worm gave up its life-breath, melting in that blood which it had drawn. All this seemed wonderful. [Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a003.htm)

One day, when Parashurama was resting on Karna's lap, Karna patiently withstood immense pain of an insect bite so as to not wake up his guru. Parashurama woke up and realized no Brahmana could withstand such pain. After finding out the truth, he cursed Karna that in crucial moments of fight, he would forget astra mantras.
So, in 3 major fights (Draupadi Swayamvara, Virata Go-grahana, Mahabharata), Karna couldn't win.

Nevertheless, there could be another aspect to his weakness, when compared to Arjuna.
Both in Ramayana & Mahabharata, the amshas or sons of **Surya (Sugriva, Karna) and Indra (Vali, Arjuna)** fight against each other.
Indra is stronger than Surya in parakrama e.g. Vali is stronger than Sugriva and Arjuna is stronger than Karna.

But, as Bhagavan clearly demonstrates, the side he is on will win irrespective of strength of fighter :

- Ramayana - Sugriva (Surya's son) + **Rama** defeat Vali (Indra's son)
- Mahabharata - Arjuna (Indra's son) + **Krishna** defeat Karna (Surya's son)

Source : Padma Purana Srishti Khanda Chapter 14. The  See verses 40 to 73

Comment: Shanti Parva is a huge interpolation in MB. Karna's 2 curses have interpolation written all over it as I've explained in [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16919/2995) answer. "the amshas or sons of Surya" - you need to cite sources for these claims.

Comment: "Karna is Surya's son" - Mahabharata is the source..

Comment: You cannot put a single link in your answer to support one conclusion and then go on to add 10 other things with no citations. This is what I meant.

Comment: the other things that were added are not claims, they are all part of mahabharata.

Comment: About 90% of the things anyone writes in an answer needs to be backed-up. In this answer I see only one link. You cannot just say 'Source: Mahabharata' that's too vague a reference for anyone to go check your unsupported claims.

Comment: Citing 90% of things requires one to cite several pages from Mahabharata. Nobody has the patience to go read them. People who are familiar with Mahabharata know these things without reference. None of the claims are unsupported, what i've presented are just facts

Comment: "People who are familiar with Mahabharata know these things without reference" - True, but references are needed for answers to be valid on this site. Lacking which they can be deleted. See [this meta policy](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/786/2995). If you find it tedious to add references, you can leave a comment instead of writing unsupported claims as answers.

Comment: @ram You should add sources for many points: 1) " in 3 major fights (Draupadi Swayamvara, Virata Go-grahana, Mahabharata), Karna couldn't win." 2) " the amshas or sons of Surya (Sugriva, Karna) and Indra (Vali, Arjuna)" 3) "Indra is stronger than Surya in parakrama e.g. Vali is stronger than Sugriva and Arjuna is stronger than Karna."

Comment: @TheDestroyer, each of these stories requires references from several pages from Mahabharata. Even if I did reference them, I can bet none is going to read through those. If people want proof for these claims, they should read entire Mahabharata because these incidents are scattered throughout. None of the points I've mentioned here are my imagination - they are just facts. Vali stronger than Sugriva is commonly known. That Karna lost in 3 wars to Arjuna is also commonly known. Which specific page in Mahabharata mentions these ?? I would need to reference an entire chapter, or the whole book

Comment: @ram You don't need to fetch online sources. You can mention Chapter numbers and Parvas in mahabharata.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Sources are not needed for things like Vali is stronger than Sugriva. Citation babber should be only used when there are not well known facts and utterly wrong claims. I think the banner can be removed.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma What not needed? One can write anything and say, Bhagavad Gita is the source, whether it is Vali stronger than Sudriva or Karna stronger than Arjuna. One should support claims by quoting proper references or sources.

Comment: For statement like "Rama is sita's husband," OP gave explanation how it is. That is enough. Citation banner should be used when there is something very much contradictory and not well known. If that statement is not the major part, then the sources are not required. If that is the main source, then we can ask for sources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Karna is described as a weak warrior because he has been defeated many times. Several Kshatriya's considered Karna as a weaker warrior. Characters considered karna to be weak and just a braggart:

[SECTION CLVII](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07154.htm) of Drona Parva, (English translation by Kisari Mohan Ganguli)

> - "Thou boastest much, O Karna, in the presence of the Kuru chief, but **thy prowess is seldom witnessed**, nor, indeed, any result (of thy boastful speeches). Many a time have **we seen thee encounter the sons of Pandu in battle.** On **every** one of those **occasions**, O Suta's son, **thou hast been vanquished by the Pandavas**. While Dhritarashtra's son was being taken away (as a captive) by the Gandharvas, all the troops fought on that occasion **except thy single self, who was the first to fly away**. In Virata's city also, all the Kauravas, united together, including **thyself** and thy younger brother **were vanquished by Partha in battle**. Thou art **not a match for even one of the sons of Pandu**, viz., Phalguna, on the field of battle. How then canst thou venture to vanquish all the sons of Pandu with Krishna at their head? Thou indulgest in too much brag, O Suta's son!"*

**Here Karna's own guru (Kripa) is claiming he is no match to the strong Pandava's.**

Comment: Is Karna's Guru Kripa? When did Karna learn under Kripacharya?

Comment: Kripa was a tutor of Karna: 
"And having acquired all the four kinds of weapons from Drona, Kripa, and Rama, he became famous in the world as a mighty bowman." https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03307.htm might bowman weaker than drona, satyaki, ashwathama, abhimanyu, arjuna, bhima, ghatotkatcha, drupada, bhisma and suvraja.

Answer (score 0):

Yes he (Karna) is. Many people degraded Karna.
**Bhisma [considered](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05169.htm) Karna weak.**

> As regards this thy ever dear friend, this one who is always boastful of his skill in battle, this one who always urgeth thee, O king, to fight with the Pandavas, this vile braggart, Karna, the son of Surya, this one who is thy counsellor, guide, and friend, this vain wight who is destitute of sense, this Karna, is neither a Ratha nor an Atiratha. Without sense, this one hath been deprived of his natural coat of mail. Always kind, he hath also been deprived of his celestial ear-rings. In consequence of the curse of Rama (his preceptor in arms) as also of the words of a Brahmana (who cursed him on another occasion), owing also to his deprivation of the accoutrements of battle, he, in my judgment, is only half a Ratha. Having approached Falguni (in battle), he will not certainly escape with life!'

**Drona considered Karna weak.**

> Hearing this, Drona, that foremost of all wielders of weapons, said, 'It is even so as thou hast said. That is not untrue! He boasteth on the eve of every battle, but yet he is seen to retreat from every engagement. Kind (out of season) and blundering, it is for this that Karna, in my judgment, is only half a Ratha!'

**Krishna considered Karna weak.**

> The Suta's son Karna, a lesser warrior, encountering Partha, came to his end on the second day, like an insect encountering a blazing fire. After the fall of Karna, the Kauravas became dispirited but lost all weakness.

Everyone should know this by now.[image]

**Source**: http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05169.htm

Comment: Tu alag nhi maan raha?

Comment: When you copy something from a site, provide proper attribution.

Comment: okay i'll show the sources by editing my answer