# who can a Mleccha marry?

Tags: varna, mleccha

Who can a Mleccha marry? A mleccha is outside the varna system,i.e they are neither brahmins, Kshatriyas, Vaisyas, or even Shudras. can a mleccha only marry a mleccha? I'm talking about a convert since he is not a Vedic person by birth.

Comment: Well Hinduism can't tell a mleccha what he can or cannot do since by the very definition they don't follow Hinduism. Btw you can be neither of the four Varna and still be Hindu e.g. mixed varna

Comment: A mleccha can only marry another mleccha.

Comment: @Carmensandiego Mlecchas aren't allowed to marry caste Indians. It's a sin for caste Indians to marry mlecchas for sure.

Comment: @ikshvaku - I feel in that case  the question should be "can Hindus marry mlecchas" not "who can a mleccha marry". The answer to latter is unequivocally "anyone they feel like"

Comment: @Carmensandiego Actually I think it's a sin even for a mleccha to marry a caste hindu.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - Maybe. But that is like saying you and I are committing sins as per Abhrahmanic faiths.

Comment: @Carmensandiego Yeah it may just be a sin for the caste Indian to marry a mleccha and not a sin for the mleccha.

Comment: I am asking because I am a Mleccha convert.I think I can only marry a mleccha woman even if Im a hindu now.because were outside the varna system,and to those saying you can choose a varna this is not so.you cant even do that as a hindu caste person without Tapas.

Comment: Yes you'll have to follow the rules of Hinduism then, so you can only marry another mleccha.

Comment: @ikshvaku,thank you,that is what I thought.and that what Id be happiest doing.

Comment: @johnyman I'm glad. You're doing the right thing.

Comment: @johnyman You can follow this answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35521/19925) if you want to remove your caste altogether.

Comment: This is not a question about Hinduism. Mlēccha by definition is a person who does not live according to our scriptures. This is like asking 'who can a Hindu marry' on a website about Christianity.