# What should a Shudra do in order to eligible to read Vedas?

Tags: vedas, guru, shudra

**Context:** I found out after a lot of research that my ancestors were either Kshatriya **or** there is some sort of story that they were sprung up from Lord Shiva. **But** neither my family from atleast 3 gens has wore the sacred thread nor I have done it till yet (I am 18). So, I am Shudra. (If you don't agree, please clarify.)

**Questions:**

1. What path should I follow in order to eligible to read Vedas?
2. What is the process of removing caste altogether after finding a guru?

Comment: For ur Q2, read the answers given under [this Q](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16417/can-a-sudra-become-a-brahmin-in-this-birth/17132#17132), specially Tejaswee's and mine. According to Tantras caste system dissolves after Diksha Samskara.

Comment: @Rickross Actually I questioned here just after reading your convo. Can you tell me how can one find a guru in my area and if caste system is dissolved then who am I (as in varna)?

Comment: @Rickross Also I would like to thank you for your help, you have helped me a lot since I joined this site!

Comment: Haha , no problem mate, I am always helpful towards people who are religious minded. seeking knowledge and who are polite like you. :) .. Regarding how can you find your Guru - That I can not say, you have to do your own hard work here .. also what that verse means is that after Diksha, there are no caste related barriers left. A Sudra who's initiated can do the same things (in the realm of spirituality and religion) that any other can do..

Comment: @Rickross Thanks, I will look around my network and see what I can do...

Comment: That's good, all the best.. And if you try hard enough, you will certainly get what you want.

Comment: @Rickross So are Brahmins also non-Brahmins after initiation too?

Comment: @Ikshvaku You've to understand the purport of the verse and not see it literally. Just like anyone who has drunk Amrita becomes immortal/god, anyone who receives the Divine Nectar thru Diksha becomes "equally divinised/pure"

Comment: @Rickross Similar concept is there in sri vaishnavism after initiation, but we don't say they literally lose their caste; i.e. shudras after initiation can't intermarry and still have to marry shudras, they still have to follow their varna dharma, can't recite mantras, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Can you cite your sources?

Comment: @Ikshvaku As I have said earlier, anyone who drinks Amrita becomes god, irrespective of who they were in their pasts. So, thereafter it is pointless to discriminate between them. At present they are all gods. If you think otherwise then either Amrita is powerless or you don't have any faith in its powers.

Comment: @Rickross Ok but can they intermarry with other castes? What happens to their kids after initiation? Are they also casteless or still have their caste?

Comment: @Ikshvaku AFAIK everyone is born Shudra until initiation (leaving outcastes). So anyway the kids will be Shudra after birth.

Comment: @ThePreserver - You are confused regarding everybody is born a Shudra..a Kshatriya child is at first only born into a Kshatriya kula..it is his sacred thread ceremony that formally inducts him into the Kshatriya varna and makes it duty bound for him to uphold Kshatra Dharma...thus they are twice born- once into Kshatriya family and then ascend to become a full fledged Kshatriya.  He was not a shudra. If that be the case, all Shudras by just donning a janeu can turn into savarnas...!